# How to model a relational database for a sales business domain?

Tags: database-design

I'm trying to come up with a solution that essentially boils down to visualising *sales* data, across many *depts*, in many *stores*, in many *areas*. The most significant challenge is a way to conceptualise/store this data in a meaningful way.

*Store* breakdown:

- 8 *stores* per *area*
- 3 *areas* per *region*
- 3 *regions* nationally

*Department* breakdown:

- 50 *micro departments* per *store* (think “chocolate”, “confectionary”, “headphones”) that belong to:
- 8 *major departments* (e.g. “chocolate” and “confectionary” belong to “grocery”, “headphones” and “CDs” belong to “entertainment”) that, in turn, belong to:
- 2 *department divisions* (each *division* would hold 4 of the *major depts*)

Sales data is generated on a *weekly* basis and then we aggregate it how we see fit. Each week a new spreadsheet is created and each *store* has three columns devoted to their store, which breaks down each *micro department*, the *sales this year*, the *sales last year* (and then we look at *% gains/losses*).

So what I'm trying to do is conceptualise a way to store the data meaningfully (all *weeks*, all *departments*, all *stores*) and then we'll perform some analysis on it later to extract what we need.

My current thinking is:

- each *store* instance would have a *store ID*, *name*, *area* & *region*.
- each *micro department* instance would have an *ID*, *name* and the *major dept* it belongs to
- each *week* would have a *week ID* (we use *financial weeks*) and alternatively a *date*
- we then create *sales* instances with a *store ID*, *department ID*, *sales TY*, *$ sales LY* and a *week #*

Is there a better way of representing the data or something that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would establish 2 hierarchies:

```
region:
    region_id (PK)
    region_name
    ...

area:
    area_id (PK)
    region_id (FK to region)
    area_name
    ...

store:
    store_id (PK)
    area_id (FK to area)
    store_name
    ...
```

and

```
division:
    division_id (PK)
    division_name
    ...

department:
    department_id (PK)
    division_id (FK to division)
    department_name
    ...

subdepartment:
    subdepartment_id (PK)
    department_id (FK to department)
    subdepartment_name
    ...
```

Since `store` is tied to `area` and `area` to `region`, you don't need to directly tie `store` to `region`. Using ID values instead of embedding the area or region names directly simply allows those things to be renamed (and they will be). Same logical holds true for `subdepartment`.

I would build the `sales_history` table with the following columns:

- `store_id`
- `subdepartment_id`
- `sales_year` - You may run your sales year from January through December, but this allows other options, without having to calculate the sales year off the date.
- `week_no` - Again, this is something that could probably be calculated off the date you record, but having it explicitly simplifies searching, comparisons, and allows it to remain correct for past years, even if the calculation for a future year is different.
- `sales_date` - Probably the first date in the week.
- `sales_amount`
- and, any other fields you need.

This will allow you to compare 2016 weeks 1-13 with 2017 weeks 1-13 at any level (store and department; region and subdepartment; whatever). You can also easily compare 2015, 2016, and 2017 (not as easy if storing this year's and last year's values in the same row).